# R - Plot pairs of data from pairs of sequential rows where available in a data frame in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, time-series, sequential

I have a data frame of time series data for multiple individuals. The data consists of surface intervals and dive intervals of animals over time for each individual. For every surface interval I would like to use ggplot to plot the duration of the surface interval against the duration of the previous dive where available. If there were two surface intervals in a row, I'd like to ignore them, and just plot surfacings that have a dive directly before them. I'd like to do this per Individual ID. 
I have supplied some example data below:

I would prefer to use the dplyr package group_by() function for individuals, but not sure how to select each dive and pair it with the following (subsequent) surfacing.

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"), 
What=c("Dive", "Surface", "Dive","Surface","Dive", "Surface", "Surface", "Dive", "Surface", "Dive", "Surface", "Dive", "Dive", "Surface", "Dive", "Surface", "Dive", "Surface"), 
Start=c("2010-05-09 17:29:45", "2010-05-09 17:56:24", "2010-05-09 18:22:15", "2010-05-09 18:52:38", "2010-05-09 18:59:02", "2010-05-09 19:24:37","2010-05-09 19:30:00", "2010-05-09 19:30:57", "2010-05-09 19:48:00","2010-05-03 18:49:35", "2010-05-03 18:58:00", "2010-05-03 19:27:51","2010-05-03 19:35:42", "2010-05-03 20:15:41", "2010-05-03 20:24:13","2010-05-03 20:53:32", "2010-05-03 21:01:31", "2010-05-03 21:40:26"), 
End=c("2010-05-09 17:56:24", "2010-05-09 18:22:15", "2010-05-09 18:52:38","2010-05-09 18:59:02", "2010-05-09 19:24:37", "2010-05-09 19:29:28","2010-05-09 19:30:57", "2010-05-09 19:48:00", "2010-05-09 19:49:02", "2010-05-03 18:58:06", "2010-05-03 19:27:51", "2010-05-03 19:35:42", "2010-05-03 20:15:41", "2010-05-03 20:24:13", "2010-05-03 20:53:32", "2010-05-03 21:01:31", "2010-05-03 21:40:26", "2010-05-03 21:48:44"), 
Duration = c(26.65, 25.85, 30.38,  6.40, 25.58,  4.85,  0.95, 17.05, 1.03,  8.52, 29.85,  7.85, 39.98,  8.53, 29.32,  7.98, 38.92,  8.30))

df$Start<-as.POSIXct(df$Start, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df$End<-as.POSIXct(df$End, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I would like to make a ggplot with the x axis as surface duration, and the y axis of the previous dive duration. If there are two dives in a row, ignore the first one and plot the second one against the next surfacing; same goes for multiple surfacings; I'd just like to pick the surfacings that have a dive right before them.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of what you're trying to do, but if I understand correctly... we can do some manipulation to get an eight-row data frame with the four dive-surface pairs for each of the two individuals:

```
df2 <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(What != lead(What) | is.na(lead(What))) %>% 
  select(ID, What, Duration) %>% 
  mutate(dive_number = ceiling(row_number() / 2)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(What, Duration)

# A tibble: 8 x 4
  ID    dive_number  Dive Surface
  <fct>       <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A               1 26.6    25.8 
2 A               2 30.4     6.4 
3 A               3 25.6     0.95
4 A               4 17.0     1.03
5 B               1  8.52   29.8 
6 B               2 40.0     8.53
7 B               3 29.3     7.98
8 B               4 38.9     8.3
```

Then you can plot the results:

```
df2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Surface, y = Dive, color = ID)) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Thanks! That's almost exactly what I wanted to get (the df2 data frame), except a few things with the rows where there are 2 surfacings or 2 dives in a row: I would want: df2
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  ID    dive_number  Dive Surface
  <fct>       <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A               1 26.6    25.8 
2 A               2 30.4     6.4 
3 A               3 25.6     4.85, not 0.95 (surfacing immediately after dive)
4 A               4 17.0     1.03
5 B               1  8.52   29.8 
6 B               2 40.0     8.53
7 B               3 29.3     7.98
8 B               4 38.9     8.3